# How to draw an image on screen (Like a logo of some sort) for FiveM LUA

Tags: image, lua, grand-theft-auto, fivem

Just a simple question with, I believe, a not so simple answer;
Is it possible with LUA to draw an image on screen?
If yes; which Native is used for that?
If no; what is an easy way to do it with another language?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua itself doesn't have functions to do that, but FiveM does. (The upshot of this is that other games that use Lua will have their own functions to draw, and won't have this one). In this case, you'll want [the `DrawSprite` function](https://runtime.fivem.net/doc/natives/#_0xE7FFAE5EBF23D890):

> ```
> -- 0xE7FFAE5EBF23D890 0x1FEC16B0
> -- DRAW_SPRITE
> DrawSprite(
>   textureDict --[[ string ]], 
>   textureName --[[ string ]], 
>   screenX --[[ number ]], 
>   screenY --[[ number ]], 
>   width --[[ number ]], 
>   height --[[ number ]], 
>   heading --[[ number ]], 
>   red --[[ integer ]], 
>   green --[[ integer ]], 
>   blue --[[ integer ]], 
>   alpha --[[ integer ]]
> )
> ```
>
> Draws a 2D sprite on the screen.   Parameters:
>
> - textureDict - Name of texture dictionary to load texture from (e.g. "CommonMenu", "MPWeaponsCommon", etc.)
> - textureName - Name of texture to load from texture dictionary (e.g. "last_team_standing_icon", "tennis_icon", etc.)
> - screenX/Y - Screen offset (0.5 = center)
> - scaleX/Y - Texture scaling. Negative values can be used to flip the texture on that axis. (0.5 = half)
> - heading - Texture rotation in degrees (default = 0.0) positive is clockwise, measured in degrees
> - red,green,blue - Sprite color (default = 255/255/255)
> - alpha - opacity level
>
> ```
> NativeDB Added Parameter 12: BOOL p11
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I believe it then isn't possible to draw a custom image on screen, my custom logo. How could I do that?

Comment: @MartijnMenssen It's possible; you just need to create a sprite with your image. If you're not sure how to do that, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Yes it's possible to draw a custom sprite; you need to use OpenIV to create a new .rpf archive, then create a .ytd file in it, and add your custom image in that ytd. Then export the ytd file and add it to a stream folder inside your resource, like `resources/your-resource/stream`. Draw it using that same function, using the .ytd file name for the textureDict param, and the image's name for the textureName param.